# passing specific data from a table by jquery ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

the application simply is
dynamic page generate html code with some data within table cells by receiving parameters
i could get these pure data by jquery
**but i find trouble sending it by ajax to another page(the basic page)** 
to display it in another format

Answer (score 0):

You could try to serialize the table into a json and pass it to the next page where you could recreate the table based on the json. Just a quick idea

Comment: what i know is to send it by json the needed data should only printed out not the entire page 
but in this example i have full html generated page
how i am gonna send the only data in cells with out the rest of page

Comment: You could itterate through the HTML table using css selectors. for example: $$('#tableID tr').each(function(elm){ //continue selecting each <td> and extract the data, store each row in a new json leve }) sorry but this comment area doesn't allow me to place code :(